# How to index through treeview.item values

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The code below changes each item in the row at each of the different columns. In this case six columns.

```
for child in treeview.getchildren():
    treeview.item(child, values=('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'))
```

Let's say I wanted to change a value of a cell in a specific row of my treeview. The treeview has 6 columns and I want to change the value of let's say the 5th column.

```
for child in treeview.get_children():
    treeview.item(x, option='values')[4]
```

The code above is to select it, but I want to change the value of '5' in let's say '10'. How would I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Treeview.set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.set):

```py
# assume column name for 5th column is 'col5'
for child in treeview.get_children():
    treeview.set(child, 'col5', '10')
```

Comment: @Swarm If it solves your question (as I notice that you have used it in your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019479/how-to-write-the-if-clause-when-iterating-through-a-treeview)), consider to accept it as the answer.